# Finding the value of a polynomial at zero

Tags: functions, polynomials

Given a polynomial $p_n(x)\,$ with $\, n \geq 0 \,$  such  that $\, p_0(x)=1 \;,\; p_1(x)=x\;$ and $\; p_n(x)=xp_{n-1}(x)-p_{n-2}(x)\;$ ,  how can I find  $\;p_{10}(0)\; $  ?

Comment: Please **do not** write titles like the one you did! Just a very short description of the problem and *then* you write down your stuff in the question's body itself. And do not write text within dollars signs without the \text command...

Comment: And other thing: do we have "a" polynomial $\,p_n(x)\,$ or *several* polynomials which depend somehow on $\,n\,$? I think that what you *really* have is a **sequence** of polynomials defined recursively and with some given values...Perhaps those $\,p\,$ aren't even polynomials...?

Comment: @DonAntonio  You're right it's very annoying, I just thought it would be more easier others, you know to see what the specifics of the question are instead of a generic description. I'll correct myself.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes you're right, the polynomial does not depend on 'n' , it's just a recursive sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Since $p_n(0)=-p_{n-2}(0), \ n\geq2,$ it follows that the sequence $p_n(0)$ is $1,0,-1,0,1,0,\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

Since $p_n(x)=xp_{n-1}(x)-p_{n-2}(x)$, it's trivial to see that $p_n(0)=-p_{n-2}(0)$. Then you can prove by induction that there is a simple closed-form expression for $p_n(0)$ when $n$ is even (and an even simpler one when $n$ is odd).

Answer (score 1):

$$p_n(0) = 0\cdot p_{n-1}(0) - p_{n-2}(0) = - p_{n-2}(0) = + p_{n-4}(0) = -p_{n-6}(0) = \cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing $x$ as $2 \cos t = e^{it} + e^{-it}$,

$$p_n(x) = x p_{n-1}(x) - p_{n-2}(x) \iff  p_{n}(x) = (e^{it}+e^{-it})p_{n-1}(x) - p_{n-2}(x)$$
has solutions of the form:

$$p_n(x) = A e^{int} + B e^{-int}$$

Throw in the initial conditions, $p_0(x) = 1$ and $p_1(x) = x$, it is not hard to see

$$A = \frac{e^{it}}{e^{it}-e^{-it}}\quad\text{and}\quad B = \frac{-e^{-it}}{e^{it}-e^{-it}}$$
This implies:
$$p_n(t) = \frac{e^{i(n+1)t}-e^{-i(n+1)t}}{e^{it}-e^{-it}} = \frac{\sin (n+1)t}{\sin t} = U_n(\cos t) = U_n(\frac{x}{2})
$$
where $U_n(x)$ is the [Chebyshev polynomails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the second kind. In particular, this means

$$p_{10}(x) = U_{10}(\frac{x}{2}) = x^{10}-9x^8+28x^6-35x^4+15x^2-1$$

and hence $p_{10}(0) = -1$. If you want $p_n(0)$ in general, you have:

$$p_n(0) = U_n(0) = \frac{\sin (n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin \frac{\pi}{2}} = \begin{cases}1,& n \equiv 0 \pmod 4\\-1, & n\equiv 2 \pmod 4\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$